# Summing over a function with symbolic output with sympy

Tags: python, sum, sympy

I'm trying to sum a function in python, using sympy. My function is

```
x=symbols('x')
def f(k):
   if k==0:
        return x
    else:
        return 1
```

If I ask what f(0) is, I get x, and I can happily ask for things like

```
integrate(f(0),(x,0,1))
```

and I get 1/2 as I would expect.

But if I write

```
summation(f(i),(i,0,3))
```

I get 4, rather than x+3. This seems a bit weird, especially since if I don't specify the function f and go for

```
f=Function('f')
```

then

```
summation(f(i),(i,0,3))
```

gives me f(0)+f(1)+f(2)+f(3). So why, when f is defined as above, do I end up with 4 rather than x+3?

Added later: I just noticed that I don't even need the symbol x for the behaviour to be not what I expect. For example

```
def f(k):
   if k==0:
        return 100
    else:
        return 1

summation(f(i),(i,0,3))
```

returns 4 rather than 103.

Comment: Since `f` is a blackbox function, sympy cannot inspect it, so sumerical integration is used I guess.

Comment: Where did `i` come from in `summation(f(i),(i,0,3))`? I get the feeling `f(i)` is just `1` here, not a function.

Comment: @user2357112 I forgot to say there should be a i=symbols('i') in there as well. And I don't think the i can be being treated as a 1, because then summation(f(i),(i,0,3)) wouldn't give me f(0)+f(1)+f(2)+f(3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `f(i)` in

```
summation(f(i),(i,0,3))
```

you're calling the `f` function:

```
def f(k):
   if k==0:
        return x
    else:
        return 1
```

which compares `i` to `0`, then returns either `x` or `1`. Since `i == 0` evaluates to `False`, it returns `1`, so you're really just summing `1` from 0 to 3.

`summation` never sees `f` at all. It just sees `1`, because the `f(i)` call is fully evaluated before `summation` runs. `summation` only sees the return value.

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense. So what should I do to get the right output (where by right, I mean f(0)+f(1)+f(2)+f(3) with the function f evaluated as I obviously intend, so giving me x+3 in my example)?

Comment: @Kirby: You should use a sympy [Piecewise](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/functions/elementary.html#piecewise) instead of a regular Python function with an `if` statement.

Answer (score 3):

As @user2357112 noted, Python functions evaluate immediately, so `f(i)` evaluates to `1` as soon as you call it (since `i` is not equal to `0`).

To create a unevaluated function you can either use `Piecewise`, like

```
expr = Piecewise((x, Eq(i, 0)), (1, True))
summation(expr, (i, 0, 3))
```

or subclass `Function` and define `eval`:

```
class f(Function):
    @classmethod
    def eval(cls, i):
        if i.is_Integer: # Checks if i is an explicit integer, like 0, and not a symbolic expression
            if i == 0:
                return x
            return 1

summation(f(i), (i, 0, 3))
```

The `eval` method tells the function when to evaluate. When it returns `None` (here when `i` is not an explicit integer), it stays unevaluated.

`Piecewise` is probably the better solution here, but subclassing `Function` is better when you have more complex logic.